# Trouble with initializing NSMutableArray in my Singleton

Tags: objective-c, singleton

I am getting a weird error, and I can't figure it out.  This takes place inside of a class that is created with the singleton pattern:

```
- (NSMutableArray *) getCurrentClasses
{
    NSMutableArray *current_classes = [[NSMutableArray init] alloc];
    NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [current_classes count]]);
    ...
}
```

When I run this, even though I literally just initialized current_classes, it gives me this error in log:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSCFArray count]: method sent to an uninitialized mutable array object'

Does anyone know what this is happening?  I initialized it literally last line.

Thanks

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You mixed up the `alloc`/`init` calls. `alloc` comes first. It should be:

```
NSMutableArray *current_classes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```